# How to configuring the Plugins SDK if the user Id has a space in between?

Tags: liferay

I have a machine in which the user ID is Jason Bourne.

Notice the empty b/w the first and last name.

An abstract from a book which I am reading-

> the plugins SDK contains a file called build.properties. Open this
>   file in a text editor. At the top of the file is a message, “DO NOT
>   EDIT THIS FILE.” I just wanted you to see that (pictured in figure
>   2.3). This file contains the settings for where you have Liferay installed and where your deployment folder is going to be, but you
>   don't want to customize this file. Instead, create a new file in the
>   same folder called `build.[username].properties`, where `[username]` is
>   your `user ID on your machine`. This is the ID you log in with every
>   day. For example, if your user name is cooldude, you would create a
>   file called build.cooldude.properties.

Do I need to create a file with the name build.Jason Bourne.properties

Will it create any problem since there is any empty space in between the names?

Comment: Haven't you tried already?

Comment: The space may cause a problem it may be something like build.jbourne.properties

Comment: You can check for your username in `Users` folder of your window installation. I think, it would be just `Jason`, so you need to use `build.jason.properties`